# What exactly is a blocking method in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

The definition of a blocking method is very clear. There is still something that puzzles me. In a Java program, if I create a thread and try to `take()` from an empty `BlockingQueue`, that thread becomes in WAITING state according to the debugger. This is as expected.

On the other hand, if I create a thread and try to call `accept()` method of `ServerSocket` class(This is also a blocking code according to the JavaDoc), I see that this thread always in RUNNING state.

I am expecting a blocking method to be parked with monitors in Java. If a method is blocking like `ServerSocket::accept`, how come this method does not progress accept line and still have the status of RUNNING?

Comment: There are ways other than monitors that code can block.

Comment: I would expect if a blocking method does not return, thread state should be WAITING, BLOCKED?Can a blocking method block the thread and state can be RUNNING?(Like ServerSocket::accept)

Comment: It sounds like you've demonstrated that's true for yourself.

Comment: I'd say a blocking method is one that waits for something else to happen before it can continue. For example, taking from a blocking queue waits for another thread to put something in the queue. Accepting a socket connection waits for some external process/system to try and connect. Reading from an input stream waits for data to be available. All those examples are different from a method simply taking a while to compute something.

Answer (score 5):

There's the concept of 'a blocking call' / 'a blocking method', as one might use in conversation, or as a tutorial might use, or even as a javadoc might use it.

Then there is the specific and extremely precisely defined `java.lang.Thread` state of `BLOCKING`.

The two concepts **do not align**, as you've already figured out with your test. The BLOCKING state effectively means 'blocking by way of this list of mechanisms that can block' (mostly, waiting to acquire a monitor, i.e. what happens when you enter a `synchronized(x)` block or try to pick up again from an `x.wait()` call: In both cases the thread needs to become 'the thread' that owns the lock on the object `x` is pointing at, and if it can't do that because another thread holds it, then the thread's state becomes BLOCKING.

This is spelled out in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html). Here's the quote:

> A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.

('monitor lock' is JVM-ese for the mechanism that `synchronized` and `obj.wait/notify/notifyAll` work with, **and nothing else**).

Keep reading the full javadoc of that page, as the detailed descriptions of these states usually spell out precisely which methods can cause these states.

This lets you figure out that if you write this code:

```
synchronized (foo) {
   foo.wait();
}
```

then that thread goes through these states, in the worst case scenario)

- RUNNING -> BLOCKED (another thread is in a `synchronized(foo)` block already).
- BLOCKED -> RUNNING (that other thread is done)
- RUNNING -> WAITING (obj.wait() is called, now waiting for a notify)
- WAITING -> BLOCKED (we've been notified, but the thread still cannot continue until that monitor is picked up again, that's how wait and notify work).
- BLOCKED -> RUNNING (got the lock on foo)

### So why is my I/O thing on RUNNING then?

Unfortunately, I/O-related blocking is **highly undefined behaviour**.

However, I can explain a common scenario (i.e. what most combinations of OS, hardware, and JVM provider end up doing).

The reason for the undefined behaviour is the same reason for the RUNNING state: Java is supposed to run on a lot of hardware/operation system combos, and most of the I/O is, in the end, just stuff that java 'farms out' to the OS, and the OS does whatever the OS is going to do. Java is not itself managing the state of these threads, it just calls on the OS to do a thing, and then the OS ends up blocking, waiting, etc. Java doesn't need to manage it; not all OSes even allow java to attempt to update this state, and in any case there'd be no point whatsoever to it for the java process, it would just slow things down, and add to the pile of 'code that needs to be custom written for *every* OS that java should run on', and that's a pile you'd prefer remain quite small. The only benefit would be for you to write code that can programatically inspect thread states... and that's more a job for agents, not for java code running inside the same VM.

But, as I said, undefined, mostly. Don't go relying on the fact that `x.get()` on a socket's InputStream will keep the thread in RUNNING state.

Similar story when you try to `interrupt()` a thread that is currently waiting in I/O mode. That means the I/O call that is currently waiting for data *might* exit immediately with some IOException (not InterruptedException, though, that is guaranteed; InterruptedException is checked, InputStream.read() isn't declared to throw it, therefore, it won't) - or, it might do nothing at all. Depends on OS, java version, hardware, vendor, etc.

Answer (score 3):

So the thread states don’t match up with OS thread states. They are defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html:

```
public static enum Thread.State
extends Enum<Thread.State>
A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:
NEW
A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
RUNNABLE
A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
BLOCKED
A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
WAITING
A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a       particular action is in this state.
TIMED_WAITING
A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
TERMINATED
A thread that has exited is in this state.
A thread can be in only one state at a given point in time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any operating system thread states.
```

When we say something is blocked or waiting, we have broad ideas about what that means. But blocked  here doesn’t mean blocked on I/O, it doesn’t mean blocked trying to acquire a ReentrantLock, it specifically means blocked trying to acquire a monitor lock. So that is why your socket accept call shows the thread as running, the definitions are very narrow. Read the rest of the linked Java doc, it is extremely specific about what qualifies as a given state.